# How to call a reference function asynchronously, from N-api, I can not get "env"!

Tags: node.js, node.js-addon, node.js-napi

js code is:

```
const obj = tap.create();
quote.on("connection", (params) => {
console.log('[DEBUG js]', 'connection called, params:', params);
});
```

remember function in c++:

```
napi_create_reference(env, args[1], 1, &cbMap[eIt->second]);
```

when native function is called:

```
void TAP_CDECL Spi::OnConnect(int errorCode, const Info *info) {

{{I want to call the function from cbMap here, How to write code? I do not 
known how to find "env"!}}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use node-addon-api solve the problem, now i found napi updated, from `https://insight.io/github.com/nodejs/node/tree/master/test/addons-napi/test_env_sharing/`, I think it is useful!